# Incremental MapReduce in c#.net

Tags: .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have data of following format..

Type    C_ID    Assitor CollectionDate       granulity  counter

A   a   10  08-08-2012 00:00    15  0.9912378

B   a   5   08-08-2012 00:00    15  0.1860929

C   b   4   08-08-2012 00:00    15  0.5345317

D   c   1   08-08-2012 00:15    15  0.8656529

E   b   1   08-08-2012 00:15    15  0.3249502

A   a   10  08-08-2012 00:15    15  0.3743117

B   a   5   08-08-2012 00:30    15  0.2608622

C   b   4   08-08-2012 00:30    15  0.0079308

D   c   1   08-08-2012 00:30    15  0.7094781

E   b   1   08-08-2012 00:45    15  0.6133461

A   a   10  08-08-2012 00:45    15  0.3035875

B   a   5   08-08-2012 00:45    15  0.6093015

C   b   4   08-08-2012 01:00    15  0.4104008

D   c   1   08-08-2012 01:00    15  0.1687753

E   b   1   08-08-2012 01:00    15  0.6627076

A   a   10  08-08-2012 01:15    15  0.1901386
.....

and so on..

I want to do incremental mapreduce on this table on hourly basis.. on CollectionDate is the field which show when the records are coming.. But all this code I want in c#.net

I have done mapReduce but problem is I am getting 3 records every 15 minutes and 12Records every hour and after 1 hour these 15 records will be reduced.. and after next 1 hour again the rest of records will be reduced on same basis..

Can I get help on this in c#.net only.. I am in deep trouble since last 20 Days..

Its excess csv file.. from where i am getting the record.. n inserting into mongodb using c#.. in mongodb its look like sumthing this: 
{ "_id": a324b2f89d2e98fa21f, "Type" : A, "C_ID" : a, "assitor" : 10, "CollectionDate" : 08-08-2012 00:00, "Granulity" : 15, "Counter" : 0.1901386 } 
{ "_id": a324b2f89d2e98a216f, "Type" : B, "C_ID" : a, "assitor" : 10, "CollectionDate" : 08-08-2012 00:00, "Granulity" : 15, "Counter" : 0.1233542 } 
{ "_id": a324b2f89d2e98a3f2c, "Type" : A, "C_ID" : b, "assitor" : 12, "CollectionDate" : 08-08-2012 00:15, "Granulity" : 12, "Counter" : 0.8134552 }
{ "_id": a324b2f89d2e98b4e2d, "Type" : B, "C_ID" : b, "assitor" : 12, "CollectionDate" : 08-08-2012 00:15, "Granulity" : 12, "Counter" : 0.3218547 }

OutputFile: 
{ "_id" : a8f3e231d456a675b23c, "CollectionDate": 08-08-2012 00:00 "AvgCounter" :  } 
{ "_id" : a8f3e232456a675a42cd, "CollectionDate": 08-08-2012 01:00 "AvgCounter" :  } 
{ "_id" : a8f3e231d46a67a0b4d2, "CollectionDate": 08-08-2012 02:00 "AvgCounter" :  }

means hourly aggregated..

Till What I have done...

```
private static void MapReduce(MongoDatabase db, String collName, BsonValue bsonValue, DateTime oldDateTime, DateTime newDateTime)
    {
        var collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(collName);
        Console.WriteLine(TotalReduction++); 
        String map = @"function() { 
                                var sample = this;
                                emit(sample.CollectionDate, {CID: sample.C_ID, count:1, CollectionTime: sample.CollectionDate});
                             }";
        String reduce = @"function(key, values) {
                                var result = {CID: '', count:0};
                                values.forEach(function(value){
                                    result.CID += value.CID;
                                    result.count += value.count;
                                    result.CollectionTime = value.CollectionTime;
                                });
                                return result;
                                }";
        var options = new MapReduceOptionsBuilder();
        IMongoQuery[] queries = { Query.EQ("CollectionTime", bsonValue) };
        options.SetOutput(MapReduceOutput.Inline);
        IMongoQuery query = Query.And(queries);
        var results = collection.MapReduce(queries[0], map, reduce);
        collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("MSS_REDUCE");
        IEnumerable<BsonDocument> bdoc = results.GetResultsAs<BsonDocument>();
        collection.InsertBatch<BsonDocument>(bdoc);
    }
```

Thanks Ravi Sharma

Comment: You have given us a flat file schema.  What do your documents look like in mongodb?

Comment: its excess csv file.. from where i am getting the record.. n inserting into mongodb using c#.. in mongodb its look like sumthing this:


{ "_id": a324b2f89d2e98fa21f, "Type" : A, "C_ID" : a, "assitor" : 10, "CollectionDate" : 08-08-2012 00:00, "Granulity" : 15, "Counter" : 0.1901386 }

{ "_id": a324b2f89d2e98fa21f, "Type" : B, "C_ID" : b, "assitor" : 12, "CollectionDate" : 08-08-2012 00:15, "Granulity" : 12, "Counter" : 0.3485126 }

Comment: And what is your intended result?  You have mentioned what you are doing and what the problem is, but not what you are trying to achieve...

Comment: OutputFile:

{ "_id" : a8f3e231d456a675b23c, "CollectionDate": 08-08-2012 00:00 "AvgCounter" : <averageOfCounter> }


{ "_id" : a8f3e232456a675a42cd, "CollectionDate": 08-08-2012 01:00 "AvgCounter" : <averageOfCounter> }


{ "_id" : a8f3e231d456a67a0b4d2, "CollectionDate": 08-08-2012 02:00 "AvgCounter" : <averageOfCounter> }

means hourly aggregated..

Comment: So you want to average the "Counter" field by the "CollectionDate" hour.  And you want to do this using incremental map reduce.  Can you post what you have tried so far and we can help you figure out what is wrong?

Comment: String map = @"function() { 
                                    var sample = this;
                                    emit(sample.CollectionDate, {CID: sample.C_ID, count:1, CollectionTime: sample.CollectionDate});
                                 }";

Comment: String reduce = @"function(key, values) {
                                    var result = {CID: '', count:0};
                                    values.forEach(function(value){
                                        result.CID += value.CID;
                                        result.count += value.count;
                                        result.CollectionTime = value.CollectionTime;
                                    });
                                    return result;
                                    }";

Comment: var options = new MapReduceOptionsBuilder();
            IMongoQuery[] queries = { Query.EQ("CollectionTime", bsonValue) };
            options.SetOutput(MapReduceOutput.Inline);
            IMongoQuery query = Query.And(queries);
            var results = collection.MapReduce(queries[0], map, reduce);
            collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("MSS_REDUCE");
            IEnumerable<BsonDocument> bdoc = results.GetResultsAs<BsonDocument>();
            collection.InsertBatch<BsonDocument>(bdoc);

Comment: Ravi, how about you update your question with this information for future participants...  I'll answer after that is done.

Comment: i have edited the question.. See if it is Ok.. n sry for ur inconvinient I am new to stackOverFlow.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm still a little unclear about your dataset.  I can point out one thing and hopefully it'll help...

In your map, you aren't emitting the actual date you want to group by, but rather the date with everything in it.  Instead, you should emit a key that has the minutes, seconds, and milliseconds removed.  In addition, if you intend on grouping by an _id, you'll need to emit that as well.

```
String map = @"function() { 
    var sample = this;
    var d = sample.CollectionDate;
    var newCollectionDate = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate(), d.getHours(), 0, 0, 0);
    emit({C_ID: sample.C_ID, CollectionDate: newCollectionDate}, {C_ID: sample.C_ID, Count: 1, CounterSum: sample.Counter, CounterAverage: 0, CollectionDate: newCollectionDate});
}";
```

Your reduce function then needs to keep track of the count and sum of the values.

```
String reduce = @"function(key, values) {
    var result = {C_ID: key.C_ID, Count:0, CounterSum: 0, CounterAverage: 0, CollectionDate: key.CollectionDate};
    values.forEach(function(value){
        result.Count += value.Count;
        result.CounterSum += value.CounterSum;
    });
    return result;
}";
```

You'll also need a finalize method to do the averaging...

```
String finalize = @"function(key, value) {
    if(value.Count > 0) {
        value.CounterAverage = value.CounterSum / value.Count;
    }
    return value;
}";
```

Hope this gets you where you need to go.

Comment: Is your CollectionDate field an actual Date or is it a string? If it is a string, you'll need to convert it to a date.  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp